# Fill Popup modal with data ASP.NET CORE MVC Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I try to make popup windows modal on `<a> link` and fill the modal with data from the controller.
I test my function and everything works fine, so data is coming to my view and I get all data that I need.

```
{"data":[{"id":45,"description":"asddadasd","dateAndTime":"09/03/2021 09:09","answered":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","ticketTypeID":2,"ticketType":null,"userId":"de31ed54-1f0c-4ca1-aea1-6b5eb40c813c","applicationUser":{"name":"Johnos Smith","streetAddress":"Neka Tamo","city":"Levanda","postalCode":"710000","clientId":null,"client":null,"role":null,"roleList":null,"clientList":null,"id":"de31ed54-1f0c-4ca1-aea1-6b5eb40c813c","userName":"email@gmail.com","normalizedUserName":"email@gmail.com","email":"email@gmail.com","normalizedEmail":"email@gmail.com","emailConfirmed":false,"passwordHash":"AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAELNpgOfeZgcXCppwc3ccXbfSMu/o3CPf8grZwufVddWf/QtLzRFSCOvh/OWwkDKQww==","securityStamp":"CYXEQMHODLAJO7UPYGDRZJ52WLBTVEKR","concurrencyStamp":"17fc92bf-d32b-48f7-bcdc-0c5e3f21ea63","phoneNumber":"062/888-321","phoneNumberConfirmed":false,"twoFactorEnabled":false,"lockoutEnd":null,"lockoutEnabled":true,"accessFailedCount":0},"clientId":null,"client":null,"status":"Otvoren"}
```

Now, I want to fill my popup modal with this data `applicationuser.name`, `applicationuser.email`, `applicationuser.phonenumber`

So far what I create is Controller Action

```
    [HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
{
    var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(x => x.ApplicationUser.Name == name);
    return Json(new { data = obj });
}
```

Here is popup PartialView.cshtml

```
@model VmSTicketing.Models.ViewModels.TicketVM

<div class="modal fade" id="userDetails">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Podaci o Useru</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Ime i Prezime</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">                       
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="ImePrezime" name="ImePrezime">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Email Adresa</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="Email" name="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Broj Telefona</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" readonly  class="form-control" id="BrTel" name="BrTel">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Klijent</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" readonly  class="form-control" id="klijent" name="klijent">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my function for popup modal which also work

Here is datatable column

```
{
                "data": "applicationUser.name",
                "width": "10%",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a id="' + data + '" class="text-info user-details"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDetails" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
                }
            },





      $("#tblData").on("click", "a.user-details", function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    /*console.log(name);*/
    $.get("/Manager/Ticket/GetByName?name=" + name, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#ImePrezime').val(result.data.applicationUser.name);
        $('#Email').val(result.data.applicationUser.email);
        $('#BrTel').val(result.data.applicationUser.phoneNumber);
        $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
    });
});
```

Here is output

[image]

Please let me know if you more additional information since I have no idea what source code to provide, but this code which I provide is I think important.
I am not sure do I need to call this function `onClick` event hendler or what else to do ?
Any help?

Comment: Hi, what does `result` giving you ?

Comment: Unfortunettly nothing

Comment: table `undefine`, id `undefine`

Comment: your click event is on tr ? it should on `a` tag because on click of `a` tag modal is open then get required id using `$(this).attr('id')` pass this to backend see what it brings back then.

Comment: @Swati I update my function right now.

Comment: does `id` giving you anything ?  change that `'/Manager/Ticket/GetAll?id='+$(this).attr('id')` because your `a` tag i think also have `id` value ..correct me if i am worng here

Comment: @Swati Nothing happened :( I really have no idea where is the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229768/discussion-between-swati-and-unknowuser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` in the anchor is `applicationUser.name` not the `applicationUser.id`, so you should write a function in the backend to get data by name like this:

```
$("#tblData").on("click", "a.user-details", function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(name);
    $.get("/Ticket/GetByName?name=" + name, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#ImePrezime').val(result.data.applicationUser.name);
        $('#Email').val(result.data.applicationUser.email);
        $('#BrTel').val(result.data.applicationUser.phoneNumber);
        $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
    })
});
```

Based on your codes, I make a working demo, codes as below:

Main View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Ticket>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";

}
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Lista tiketa</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Upsert"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Novi tiket</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme slanja</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka</th>
                <th>Korisnik</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<partial name="UserDetails" />


@section Scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Ticket/GetAll"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "description", "width": "10%" },
                    { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "15%" },
                    { "data": "status", "width": "10%" },
                    { "data": "answered", "width": "15%" },
                    {
                        "data": "applicationUser.name",
                        "width": "10%",
                        "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a id="' + data + '" class="text-info user-details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDetails" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        })

        $("#tblData").on("click", "a.user-details", function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(name);
            $.get("/Ticket/GetByName?name=" + name, function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#ImePrezime').val(result.data.applicationUser.name);
                $('#Email').val(result.data.applicationUser.email);
                $('#BrTel').val(result.data.applicationUser.phoneNumber);
                $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
            })
        });
    
    </script>
}
```

Partial View (no changes):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="userDetails">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Podaci o Useru</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Ime i Prezime</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="ImePrezime" name="ImePrezime">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Email Adresa</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="Email" name="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Broj Telefona</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="BrTel" name="BrTel">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var obj = GetAllData();
    return Json(new { data = obj });
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
{
    var obj = GetUser(name);
    return Json(new { data = obj });
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey, where is implementation of `GetAllData` and `GetUser` ?

Comment: It''s fake code, you just get the data use your function.

Comment: Let me test it and I will come back in few minutes :)

Comment: I get error message 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: When you click the anchor?

Comment: Yes, when I click on anchor I get this error

Comment: What return data do you need ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229813/discussion-between-mj1313-and-unknowuser).

Answer (score 1):

Try this Hopefully your error will be resolve.

```
        $('#ImePrezime').val(result.ticketTable.row(this).data()[1]);
        $('#Email').val(result.ticketTable.row(this).data()[2]);
        $('#BrTel').val(result.ticketTable.row(this).data()[3]);
```

Comment: Try this `$('#Email').val(result.data.applicationUser.email)`